# How to print out the current sql query in php with sqlsrv?

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I want to log SQL queries (especially INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE) to import these DB changes to the same DB on another server.
I use PHP and SQLSRV to execute my queries as follows:

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET column = 0 WHERE id = (?)";
$params = array($myid);
sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params);
```

Now I want to store the complete SQL query (including the params) to a log table. I hoped I can do this with trigger and tried something like the following:

```
SELECT dest.text
FROM   sys.dm_exec_requests dem CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(dem.sql_handle) dest
WHERE  session_id = @@SPID
```

But this always returns itself.
The following seems to be better:

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 'DBCC INPUTBUFFER(' + CAST(@@SPID AS nvarchar(100)) + ')'
CREATE TABLE #SQL (
    EventType varchar(100),
    Parameters int,
    EventInfo nvarchar(max)
)
INSERT INTO #SQL
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
SELECT @sql = EventInfo FROM #SQL
DROP TABLE #SQL
```

After that, @sql contains something like

```
(@P1 int)UPDATE table SET column = 0 WHERE id = (@P1)
```

But there are no params...
Is there any way to get the full SQL query including the parameters?

Otherwise I think I have to change all my queries in PHP and don't use the '$params' parameter of sqlsrv_query().

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a second query, which takes previous query string as a parameter:

```
$query = "UPDATE table SET column = 0 WHERE id = (?)";
$fullQuery = "UPDATE table SET column = 0 WHERE id = ($myid)";
```

And pass `$fullQuery` as a parameter to another query:

```
...
$sampleQuery = "INSERT INTO logTable (Query) VALUES (?)";
$sampleParams = array($fullQuery);

sqlsrv_query($conn, $sampleQuery, $sampleParams);
...
```

I think you know why parameterized queries are used (avoiding SQL injection), so I suggest not to give up using parameters if you are not really sure the queries will be totally safe.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing now (with a little function which does the logging stuff). I still hoped that there is an easier way, because now I have to do the conversion stuff of the different datatypes on my own (int, string, DateTimes, etc.) and I have to change every affected SQL query to use my own function instead of sqlsrv_query().